# Can't pass props to Route component={{}} but can't access location.pathname in Route render={{}}

Tags: reactjs, routes, components, render

### Description

So I'm having the following route:
`<Route path='/' component={RedirectUser} />`
which allows me to use `this.props.location.pathname` in my RedirectUser component. Except, now I have to use some props; so I changed my route like this: 
`<Route path='/' MyState={this.state.MyState} render={() => <RedirectUser />} />`
But apparently, this way doesn't allow me to use this `this.props.location.pathname` as I suddenly can't acces these props anymore.

### Question

How can I still access my location props if I use a Route render={{}} ?

Comment: Check the duplicated answer and observe how it passes the props to the render arrow function as a parameter and for the component.

Comment: The duplicated answer helped! Thanks :)